# which ip address to connect after setting Fully Distributed Deployment for wso2 sp

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I have set up a fully distributed deployment for wso2 stream processor. 
following is the configuration:
  1. 192.168.0.1 and  192.168.0.2 has manager nodes running with state 
   management db in 192.168.0.3.

2. 192.168.0.1,  192.168.0.2 and 192.168.0.4 also has worker nodes

So i had query as to which ip address i need to be using to push my siddhi query(192.168.0.1:9543 or 192.168.0.2:9543) Or do i need a reverse proxy for this.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to push the siddhi files to both manager nodes(192.168.0.1:9543 and 192.168.0.2:9543). Refer [1]

It is recommended to use a content synchronization mechanism since Siddhi applications must be deployed to both manager nodes. You can use a common shared file system such as Network File System (NFS) or any other shared file system that is available. You need to mount the SP_HOME/wso2/manager/deployment/siddhi-files/ directory of the two nodes to the shared file system.[2]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP410/Stream+Processor+REST+API+Guide

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP410/Fully+Distributed+Deployment